# KeyError during Lookup for reference to crosstables

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, lookup

I have a data frame of :

```
dfAll = match ID    Team A Hero 1.1 Team A Hero 1.2   Team A Hero 1.3
     123124140         (1, 2)            (2, 3)            (1, 3)
     123123124         (4, 1)            (3, 4)            (1, 5)
```

and so on..

and I have a crosstable:

```
dfEloCross =     1     2     3     4     5
             1  NaN  -1.0  +2.0  -8.0   +5.0

             2  +1.0  NaN  +2.5  +3.0    0

             3  -2.0 -2.5  NaN   +5.5   -3.5

             4  +8.0 -3.0  -5.5  NaN   +2.8

             5  -5.0   0   +3.5  -2.8    NaN
```

And I wanted for each matchup to return a value as so, where it is vertical against horizontal.

```
df1 = matchups 1    matchups 2    matchups 3
       +1.0           -2.5         -2.0
       -8.0           -5.5         -5.0
```

I've tried using this code:

```
for uv in range(1, 6):
for xv in range(1,6):
    dfAll['Matchup' + ' ' + str(uv) + '.' + str(xv)] = dfAll['Team A Hero' + ' ' + str(uv) + '.' + str(xv)].apply(lambda x: dfEloCross.lookup([x[0]],[x[1]])[0])
```

And it works fine for the first column of `Team A Hero 1.1`

But
returns key error for others
`KeyError: 'One or more column labels was not found`

I'm a beginner so I would love to get all the help I can get. Thanks in Advance!

**EDIT**

For reference, here's a snippet of my dataframe:

`dfAll =  {'Team A Hero 1.1': {0: '(22, 21)', 1: '(12, 3)', 2: '(6, 7)', 3: '(13, 18)', 4: '(28, 7)', 5: '(9, 36)', 6: '(36, 7)', 7: '(9, 7)', 8: '(4, 61)'}, 'Team A Hero 1.2': {0: '(22, 43)', 1: '(12, 15)', 2: '(6, 31)', 3: '(13, 49)', 4: '(28, 13)', 5: '(9, 58)', 6: '(36, 13)', 7: '(9, 8)', 8: '(4, 64)'}, 'Team A Hero 1.3': {0: '(22, 71)', 1: '(12, 30)', 2: '(6, 40)', 3: '(13, 64)', 4: '(28, 56)', 5: '(9, 78)', 6: '(36, 30)', 7: '(9, 13)', 8: '(4, 72)'}, 'Team A Hero 1.4': {0: '(22, 77)', 1: '(12, 65)', 2: '(6, 43)', 3: '(13, 65)', 4: '(28, 87)', 5: '(9, 95)', 6: '(36, 80)', 7: '(9, 15)', 8: '(4, 76)'}, 'Team A Hero 1.5': {0: '(22, 85)', 1: '(12, 103)', 2: '(6, 69)', 3: '(13, 107)', 4: '(28, 106)', 5: '(9, 107)', 6: '(36, 98)', 7: '(9, 112)', 8: '(4, 84)'}, 'Team A Hero 2.1': {0: '(28, 21)', 1: '(58, 3)', 2: '(20, 7)', 3: '(54, 18)', 4: '(44, 7)', 5: '(28, 36)', 6: '(49, 7)', 7: '(52, 7)', 8: '(51, 61)'}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to use nested loops. Instead, you can use the [`pd.DataFrame.lookup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html) method available to Pandas.

In this case, you can iterate your Team columns, unpack your coordinates and perform your lookup one series at a time:

```
from ast import literal_eval

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'matchID': [123124140, 123123124],
                    'TeamA_1.1': ['(1, 2)', '(4, 1)'],
                    'TeamA_1.2': ['(2, 3)', '(3, 4)']})

# convert mapping table columns to integer type
dfEloCross.columns = dfEloCross.columns.astype(int)

# calculate columns which need mapping
team_cols = df1.columns[df1.columns.str.startswith('Team')]

# cycle each column, strip column & row coordinates and use with lookup
for col in team_cols:
    c, r = zip(*df1[col].apply(literal_eval))
    df1[col] = dfEloCross.lookup(r, c)

print(df1)

   TeamA_1.1  TeamA_1.2    matchID
0        1.0       -2.5  123124140
1       -8.0       -5.5  123123124
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately for me, it still returns this error `'One or more row labels was not found'`

Comment: That's interesting. Unfortunately, I can't reproduce your error. If you are able to share some code (as I've done) to demonstrate the problem, I may be able to help.

Comment: I would love to, the problem is that its a pretty big code, how do I share it properly?

Comment: See [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

Comment: So it looks like you have strings, not tuples, in your dataframe. You can try using `ast.literal_eval` as per my update.

Comment: Interesting that it works on the dataframe that I gave you but when applied to my larger dataframe it again returns the same error, I'll try to replicate the error on my post again. I just wanted to say thanks for all the help. I'm really grateful. Could it be duplicate errors? The code works on the first column but not the second

Comment: Thanks for all the help!! Turns out there were some missing values that resulted in tuples (1,") and returned an error, fixed and it worked!!